# как загрузить файлы на веб сервер и обратиться к ним (Flask)

Tags: python, сервер, flask

У меня есть веб сервер (http://127.0.0.1:5000), на него мне нужно загрузить файлы и читать их через код на python 3.
Вопрос первый: Как узнать директорию в которой работает сервер?
Вопрос второй: как через Python 3 обратиться к этим файлам и читать их?

Comment: В документации Flask есть раздел, который так и называется [Uploading Files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/). Ну а про обращение к файлам в Python это же ж самые основы языка, которые описаны в любом учебнике https://tproger.ru/articles/files-in-python/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как обратиться именно к фалам на сервере?